# Docker Unmet dependencies: nvidia-docker2

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

When I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
```

I got the following error response:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-docker2 : Depends: docker-ce (= 18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not installable or
                           docker-ee (= 18.06.1~ee~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/apt/sources.list` make sure the last word is stable, not edge

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

In my case the above line was missing in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` . I added it at the bottom & executed the following commands:

Then the usual:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

Verify your docker version with:

```
sudo docker version
```